# Matrix offset to the right due to margin

Tags: margins, matrices

I'm very new with LaTeX, so excuse my simple question. I'm writing an article document and I have specified a margin of 1.5 inches using

```
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
```

However, this leads to an undesired offset for things like matrices (see image) not being exactly centered horizontally:

[image]

Is there any way to apply the margin solely to the text or keep the matrix centered?

This is the matrix:

```
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1.000000000000000e+00 & 0.000000000000000e+00 & 0.000000000000000e+00 & 0.000000000000000e+00 \\
6.400000000000002e-02 & 2.880000000000000e-01 & 4.320000000000001e-01 & 2.160000000000000e-01 \\
-1.250000000000000e-01 & 1.125000000000000e+00 & -3.375000000000000e+00 & 3.375000000000000e+00 \\
-3.429999999999999e-01 & 2.499000000000000e+00 & -6.068999999999998e+00 & 4.912999999999999e+00 \\
-7.289999999999998e-01 & 4.616999999999998e+00 & -9.747000000000000e+00 & 6.858999999999999e+00 \\
-1.331000000000000e+00 & 7.623000000000002e+00 & -1.455300000000000e+01 & 9.261000000000001e+00 \\
-2.196999999999999e+00 & 1.166100000000000e+01 & -2.063099999999999e+01 & 1.216700000000000e+01 \\
-4.096000000000001e+00 & 1.996800000000001e+01 & -3.244800000000000e+01 & 1.757600000000000e+01 \\
-5.831999999999998e+00 & 2.721599999999999e+01 & -4.233599999999999e+01 & 2.195199999999999e+01 \\
-8.000000000000000e+00 & 3.600000000000000e+01 & -5.400000000000000e+01 & 2.700000000000000e+01 \\
-1.757600000000000e+01 & 7.300800000000001e+01 & -1.010880000000000e+02 & 4.665600000000001e+01 \\
-5.065300000000001e+01 & 1.930290000000000e+02 & -2.451990000000000e+02 & 1.038230000000000e+02 \\
-7.408800000000001e+01 & 2.751840000000000e+02 & -3.407040000000000e+02 & 1.406080000000000e+02 \\
-1.038230000000000e+02 & 3.777390000000001e+02 & -4.581090000000000e+02 & 1.851930000000000e+02 \\
-1.105920000000000e+02 & 4.008960000000000e+02 & -4.844160000000000e+02 & 1.951120000000000e+02 \\
-1.250000000000000e+02 & 4.500000000000000e+02 & -5.400000000000000e+02 & 2.160000000000000e+02 \\
-1.574640000000000e+02 & 5.598720000000002e+02 & -6.635520000000001e+02 & 2.621440000000001e+02 \\
-2.053790000000000e+02 & 7.205670000000001e+02 & -8.426970000000001e+02 & 3.285090000000001e+02 \\
-2.874960000000000e+02 & 9.931679999999998e+02 & -1.143648000000000e+03 & 4.389759999999999e+02 \\
-3.430000000000000e+02 & 1.176000000000000e+03 & -1.344000000000000e+03 & 5.120000000000000e+02 \\\end{bmatrix}
$$
```

Comment: Why not use a smaller margin? And do you really  need all those decimal digits?

Comment: @Bernard it works fine with a smaller margin but I'm trying to be consistent with my previous reports. And the number of decimal digits is imposed by the Professor.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried, so that we don't have to type everything from a screenshot?

Comment: you have specified the width of the text block and specified the size of the matrix (all those trailing 0 don't actually make it readable) but given the constraints you have set then you need to use a smaller font to make it fit, you could of course stick it in the left margin with `\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}...` but no publication would do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possibilities for such huge matrices: either  you locally enlarge the text area, combined with the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` (ca 80% of `\displaystyle`), or you use the `bsmallmatrix(*)` environment provided by `mathtools` (hardly readable).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb, nccmath}
\usepackage{bigstrut, changepage, lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2em}{-2em}
    \[ \medmath{\begin{bmatrix*}[r]
1.000000000000000\,e+00 & 0.000000000000000\,e+00 & 0.000000000000000\,e+00 & 0.000000000000000\,e+00 \bigstrut[t]\\
6.400000000000002\,e-02 & 2.880000000000000\,e-01 & 4.320000000000001\,e-01 & 2.160000000000000\,e-01 \\
-1.250000000000000\,e-01 & 1.125000000000000\,e+00 & -3.375000000000000\,e+00 & 3.375000000000000\,e+00 \\
-3.429999999999999\,e-01 & 2.499000000000000\,e+00 & -6.068999999999998\,e+00 & 4.912999999999999\,e+00 \\
-7.289999999999998\,e-01 & 4.616999999999998\,e+00 & -9.747000000000000\,e+00 & 6.858999999999999\,e+00 \\
-1.331000000000000\,e+00 & 7.623000000000002\,e+00 & -1.455300000000000\,e+01 & 9.261000000000001\,e+00 \\
-2.196999999999999\,e+00 & 1.166100000000000\,e+01 & -2.063099999999999\,e+01 & 1.216700000000000\,e+01 \\
-4.096000000000001\,e+00 & 1.996800000000001\,e+01 & -3.244800000000000\,e+01 & 1.757600000000000\,e+01 \\
-5.831999999999998\,e+00 & 2.721599999999999\,e+01 & -4.233599999999999\,e+01 & 2.195199999999999\,e+01 \\
-8.000000000000000\,e+00 & 3.600000000000000\,e+01 & -5.400000000000000\,e+01 & 2.700000000000000\,e+01 \\
-1.757600000000000\,e+01 & 7.300800000000001\,e+01 & -1.010880000000000\,e+02 & 4.665600000000001\,e+01 \\
-5.065300000000001\,e+01 & 1.930290000000000\,e+02 & -2.451990000000000\,e+02 & 1.038230000000000\,e+02 \\
-7.408800000000001\,e+01 & 2.751840000000000\,e+02 & -3.407040000000000\,e+02 & 1.406080000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.038230000000000\,e+02 & 3.777390000000001\,e+02 & -4.581090000000000\,e+02 & 1.851930000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.105920000000000\,e+02 & 4.008960000000000\,e+02 & -4.844160000000000\,e+02 & 1.951120000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.250000000000000\,e+02 & 4.500000000000000\,e+02 & -5.400000000000000\,e+02 & 2.160000000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.574640000000000\,e+02 & 5.598720000000002\,e+02 & -6.635520000000001\,e+02 & 2.621440000000001\,e+02 \\
-2.053790000000000\,e+02 & 7.205670000000001\,e+02 & -8.426970000000001\,e+02 & 3.285090000000001\,e+02 \\
-2.874960000000000\,e+02 & 9.931679999999998\,e+02 & -1.143648000000000\,e+03 & 4.389759999999999\,e+02 \\
-3.430000000000000\,e+02 & 1.176000000000000\,e+03 & -1.344000000000000\,e+03 & 5.120000000000000\,e+02 \bigstrut[b]
\end{bmatrix*}} \]%
\end{adjustwidth}

\[\medmath{\begin{bsmallmatrix*}[r]
1.000000000000000\,e+00 & 0.000000000000000\,e+00 & 0.000000000000000\,e+00 & 0.000000000000000\,e+00{ \bigstrutjot =2ex\bigstrut[t]}\\
6.400000000000002\,e-02 & 2.880000000000000\,e-01 & 4.320000000000001\,e-01 & 2.160000000000000\,e-01 \\
-1.250000000000000\,e-01 & 1.125000000000000\,e+00 & -3.375000000000000\,e+00 & 3.375000000000000\,e+00 \\
-3.429999999999999\,e-01 & 2.499000000000000\,e+00 & -6.068999999999998\,e+00 & 4.912999999999999\,e+00 \\
-7.289999999999998\,e-01 & 4.616999999999998\,e+00 & -9.747000000000000\,e+00 & 6.858999999999999\,e+00 \\
-1.331000000000000\,e+00 & 7.623000000000002\,e+00 & -1.455300000000000\,e+01 & 9.261000000000001\,e+00 \\
-2.196999999999999\,e+00 & 1.166100000000000\,e+01 & -2.063099999999999\,e+01 & 1.216700000000000\,e+01 \\
-4.096000000000001\,e+00 & 1.996800000000001\,e+01 & -3.244800000000000\,e+01 & 1.757600000000000\,e+01 \\
-5.831999999999998\,e+00 & 2.721599999999999\,e+01 & -4.233599999999999\,e+01 & 2.195199999999999\,e+01 \\
-8.000000000000000\,e+00 & 3.600000000000000\,e+01 & -5.400000000000000\,e+01 & 2.700000000000000\,e+01 \\
-1.757600000000000\,e+01 & 7.300800000000001\,e+01 & -1.010880000000000\,e+02 & 4.665600000000001\,e+01 \\
-5.065300000000001\,e+01 & 1.930290000000000\,e+02 & -2.451990000000000\,e+02 & 1.038230000000000\,e+02 \\
-7.408800000000001\,e+01 & 2.751840000000000\,e+02 & -3.407040000000000\,e+02 & 1.406080000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.038230000000000\,e+02 & 3.777390000000001\,e+02 & -4.581090000000000\,e+02 & 1.851930000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.105920000000000\,e+02 & 4.008960000000000\,e+02 & -4.844160000000000\,e+02 & 1.951120000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.250000000000000\,e+02 & 4.500000000000000\,e+02 & -5.400000000000000\,e+02 & 2.160000000000000\,e+02 \\
-1.574640000000000\,e+02 & 5.598720000000002\,e+02 & -6.635520000000001\,e+02 & 2.621440000000001\,e+02 \\
-2.053790000000000\,e+02 & 7.205670000000001\,e+02 & -8.426970000000001\,e+02 & 3.285090000000001\,e+02 \\
-2.874960000000000\,e+02 & 9.931679999999998\,e+02 & -1.143648000000000\,e+03 & 4.389759999999999\,e+02 \\
-3.430000000000000\,e+02 & 1.176000000000000\,e+03 & -1.344000000000000\,e+03 & 5.120000000000000\,e+02\bigstrutjot=1.6ex
 \bigstrut[b]
\end{bsmallmatrix*}} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]